# My Action on Google Assistant was deployed on 5th Nov but still I haven't got any email of SWAGS

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, activesupport, google-developers-console

My action on Google Assistant was successfully deployed on 5th November 2019 but I haven't received any mails regarding the SWAGS.

Comment: If by SWAGS, you mean the developer rewards, you should contact Actions on Google support and ask them, the reward system is a procedure handled by Google and can vary in time depending on the amount of deployed applications. https://developers.google.com/assistant/support

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the [Google Assistant Developer Community Program](https://developers.google.com/assistant/community/developer-community-program), the program ended at the end of September 2019.